# timestamp is not read by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a timestamp that looks like this: "1994-10-01:00:00:00" and when I've trying with pd.read_csv or pd.read_table to read this dataset, it imports everything including the date column ([0]) but not even as an object. This is part of my code:

```
namevar = ['timestamp', 'nsub',
       'sub_cms',             # var 1 [cms]
       'sub_gwflow',          # var 2 [cfs]
       'sub_interflow',       # var 3 [cfs]
       'sub_sroff',           # var 4 [cfs]
       ....
       'subinc_sroff',        # var 13
       'subinc_tavgc']        # var 14           

df = pd.read_csv(root.anima, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1, header=avar+6, index_col=0,
             names=namevar, infer_datetime_format=True,
             parse_dates=[0])

print(df)
```

Results in:

```
                     nsub  sub_cms  ...  subinc_sroff  subinc_tavgc
timestamp

1994-10-01:00:00:00     1   4.4180  ...           0.0      59.11000
1994-10-01:00:00:00     2   2.6690  ...           0.0      89.29000
1994-10-01:00:00:00     3   4.3170  ...           0.0      77.02000
...
2000-09-30:00:00:00     2   2.3580  ...           0.0       0.19570
2000-09-30:00:00:00     3   2.2250  ...           0.0       0.73340
2000-09-30:00:00:00     4   0.8876  ...           0.0       0.07124
[8768 rows x 15 columns]


print(df.dtypes)
```

Results in:

```
nsub                  int64
sub_cms             float64
sub_gwflow          float64
sub_interflow       float64
sub_sroff           float64
subinc_actet        float64
...
subinc_sroff        float64
subinc_tavgc        float64
dtype: object
```

my ultimate goal is that once the timestamp is in the dataframe I could modify it by getting rid of the time, with:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y%m%d', infer_datetime_format=True)
```

but when I run this now, it is telling me " KeyError: 'timestamp' "

Any help in getting the timestamp in the dataframe is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your data not as picture. Please paste the data so that everybody can copy and paste your data and algorithm to help you easily

Comment: It seems that your df does not have a timestamp column. you can assing names to your columsn using parameter names=['timestamp',...] in read_csv function call

Comment: @D-E-N, I made some edits to my post. Hopefully it is more clear now.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @MhDG7 : Thanks for your comment. Yes I already had the timestamp column, just didn't include it in the original post. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted by @s13wr81, the way bring 'timstamp' into the dataframe as a column was by removing *index_col='timestamp'* from the statement.

In order to edit timestamp properly, I needed to remove the :Hr:Min:Sec portion of it by using:

```
df['timestamp'] = df.timestamp.str.split(":", expand=True)
```

and then to convert timestamp as a Panda datetime I used:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y%m%d', infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the timestamp is in a non-standard format.  There is a colon between the date and time parts.  Here is a way to convert the value in the example:

```
import datetime

# note ':' between date part and time part
raw_timestamp = '1994-10-01:00:00:00'
format_string = '%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S'
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(raw_timestamp, format_string)

print(result)
1994-10-01 00:00:00
```

You could use pd.to_datetime() with the format_string in this example, to process an entire column of timestamps.

UPDATE

Here is an example that uses a modified version of the original data (timestamp + one column; every entry is unique):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''timestamp  nsub  
1994-10-01:00:00:00  1   
1994-10-02:00:00:00  2   
1994-10-03:00:00:00  3   
2000-09-28:00:00:00  4   
2000-09-29:00:00:00  5   
2000-09-30:00:00:00  6   
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], 
                                 format='%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S', 
                                 errors='coerce')
print(df, end='\n\n')
print(df.dtypes)

   timestamp  nsub
0 1994-10-01     1
1 1994-10-02     2
2 1994-10-03     3
3 2000-09-28     4
4 2000-09-29     5
5 2000-09-30     6

timestamp    datetime64[ns]
nsub                  int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, that colon is something I was planning to get rid of by using pd.to_datetime(), but I still need Pandas to recognize the 'timestamp' column in the imported file using pd.read_csv to have it available in the dataframe first. Once in the dataframe I could do this correction. I could 'edit' the file with a Text Editor before importing using Pandas, but I was hoping that I could save me that effort as I have many files like this. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I am trying to implement what you suggested now that I have the 'timestamp' column in the Dataframe [I removed the timestamp column as Index]. Since I have to apply it to a series I am using: **date_series=df['timestamp'].apply(datetime.strptime, args=('%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S',))**  But I am getting an error saying that _module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'_  And yes, I am importing datetime..

Comment: Please see the UPDATE part of my post, to address the follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the data, but i think timestamp is not a column, but index. this kind of problem, sometimes happen when we doing grouping.
Try :

```
"timestamp" in df.columns
```

if the result false, then :

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

next to strip time in timestamp try :

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp,unit='ns')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Yes, I removed 'timestamp' from the index column and that helped by bringing it into the Dataframe, but its non-standard format can't be modified by  _pd.to_datetime_.  cheers,

Comment: You can try : df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].astype(str).str[:10] then df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp,unit='ns')

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv(root.anima, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1, header=avar+6, index_col=0,
         names=namevar, infer_datetime_format=True,
         parse_dates=[0])
```

I think you are explicitly telling pandas to consider column 0 as the index which happens to be your datetime column.

Kindly try removing the `index_col=0` from the `pd.read_csv()` and i think it will work.

Comment: True, I made that correction and now I have it in the dataframe as a 'timestamp' object dtype.   I wanted to modify the 'timestamp' column with  _df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y%m%d', infer_datetime_format=True)_  but I am getting an 'Unknown string format' error.    Thanks for your help !